# Image of a subgroup under the quotient map

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

When going about my mathematical business, I often feel my group theoretic shortcomings very sorely. Here is an example:

> Let $G$ be a group, $Z(G)$ the centre of $G$, and $\pi: G \to G/Z(G)$ the canonical projection.
>
> Let $H < G$ be a subgroup.
>
> Is it true that $\pi(H) \cong H/Z(H)$?

This is of course a special case of the more general situation in which we want to understand the images of subgroups $H < G$ under the quotient map $\pi: G \to G/N$, where $N \vartriangleleft G$ is a normal subgroup.

I have looked through several textbooks on elementary group theory but have found no allusion to the above.

A reference or a proof/counterexample would be very helpful.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Suppose the center of $G$ is trivial, but that $H$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not the case. $Z(H)$ can contain elements that $Z(G)$ doesn't, because commuting with all of $H$ is less restrictive than commuting with all of $G$. So $Z(H)$ being larger than $Z(G)\cap H$ is not impossible at all.

Take $G=S_5$, for instance. Then $Z(G)=\{e\}$. However, if $H$ is any of several possible non-trivial abelian subgroups, then $Z(H)=H$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. So equality does not hold in general, but does it hold in some particular cases? The special case that I was considering is images of finite groups of $H<\textrm{GL}(V)$ for a vector space $V$ under the projection $\textrm{GL}(V) \to \textrm{PGL}(V) \cong \textrm{GL}(V)/Z(V)$, where $Z(V)$ denotes the group of homotheties on $V$ (i.e. the centre of $\textrm{GL}(V)$). So from the general linear group on $V$ to the projective general linear group on $V$. Here I believe the equality $\pi(H) \cong H/Z(H)$ does hold.

Comment: @HeinrichWagner, the same issue applies [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/7256676), essentially as mentioned by [@‍lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/7256434).  For example, consider $H = \{\operatorname{diag}(a, b) \mathrel: a^2 = b^2 = 1\}$, where $\pi(H)$ has order $2$ but $H/{\operatorname Z(H)}$ is trivial.  In fact this answer gives a necessary and sufficient condition for the usual map $\pi(H) \to H/{\operatorname Z(H)}$ to be an isomorphism, namely, that $\operatorname Z(H)$ equals $H \cap \operatorname Z(G)$.